# Problems when connecting to Appfog's SQL service from Flask

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, appfog

I'm currently trying to get my Flask app working with Appfog. I'm having 500 error every time I'm trying to do something with my DB. My connection code looks like:

```
services = json.loads(os.environ.get("VCAP_SERVICES"))
pg = services["postgresql-9.1"][0]["credentials"]

app.config.update({
  'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': "postgresql://%s:%s@%s:%i/%s" % \
    (pg["username"], pg["password"], pg["host"], pg["port"], pg["name"])
})

# I've tried MySQL too
```

Model:

```
class User(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  username = db.Column(db.String(40), unique=True)
  passhash = db.Column(db.String(140))

  def __init__(self, username, password):
    self.username = username
    self.passhash = pwd_context.encrypt(password)

  def check_password(self, password):
    return pwd_context.verify(password, self.passhash) # from passlib

  # Flask-Login properties
  def is_authenticated(self): return True
  def is_active(self): return True
  def is_anonymous(self): return False
  def get_id(self): return unicode(self.id)
```

And some example route that utilizes DB:

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
  if current_user.is_authenticated():
    logout_user()
  if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.form.get('username')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    if not user or not user.check_password(password):
      flash('Wrong username or password.')
      return render_template('login.html')
    else:
      login_user(user)
      return redirect(request.args.get("next") or "/")
  else:
    return render_template('login.html')
```

This works with sqlite database on localhost. So, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When running flask, run in [debug mode](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#debug-mode) to help with figuring out exact what the error is. It is too difficult to determine what the error is just from looking at your code. If you can't figure it out, add the information you determine in the debug page to your question.

Comment: @MarkHildreth I've already enabled debug mode. The weird thing about it is that it doesn't output any logs by Flask itself, just some gunicorn stuff, like so: https://gist.github.com/ale110/8656419

Comment: What happens when you try to run this without gunicorn using the debug server?

Comment: Haven't tried running it with Postgres on localhost yet. With SQLite it works well.